# What should I use, Redirect or history.replace, in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to implement login functionality in my react app. So, which one is better to use `history.replace()` or `<Redirect />` in terms of performance.

Edit 1 :

Suppose I have the below two comp.

```
const Comp1 =() => {
 // statement A
 // statement B
 // statement C
 return(
  <Redirect /> //to login
//more content
 )
}
```

Comp2

```
const Comp2 =() => {
history.replace() //to login
 // statement A
 // statement B
 // statement C
 return(
  <div>Content</div>
 )
}
```

Which of the two is more recommended to use ? How program will flow ?

Comment: I don't think you should be concerned with performance just yet... The more important distinction here is the following: `history.replace()` is an *imperative* way to navigate, while `<Redirect />` is *declarative*.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are fine. In your code two different approach is there.

1. Redirect method:
   you can direct another page.but problem is you not get history.previous state value. when user click on browser back button.
2. history.replace:
   It also used for load another page. It maintain the history.previous state value. when user click on browser back button. It back previous page.

So, it depends your requirement. I hope this solution it's help you. let me know if you not understand.